# Submit text field in Django template with js-upload-photos button

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-templates, django-2.2

I have Django app to upload photos, following the great example at [Simple Is Better Than Complex](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/11/22/django-multiple-file-upload-using-ajax.html). That part works fine. I would like to add a feature that allows a user to type in text that will be applied to all the photos they upload (which is a field in the model).

I tried just adding `{{ form.as_p }}` in the template form, but that just created a separate form with a separate button.

Next, I added a text input field to the template, but nothing seems to happen with that since the button is `type=button` rather than `submit`. Then I tried adding some jquery/javascript to submit that text field, but that returned an error `Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.)`.

Can anyone tell me how to efficiently and correctly submit a text field  to a Django view with this type of button? Or is there a good solution for the CSRF token error? Relevant pieces of code below.

```
<!-- images_upload.html -->
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% load staticfiles %}

{% block content %}

  {% block javascript %}

    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>

    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-file-upload/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-file-upload/jquery.iframe-transport.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-file-upload/jquery.fileupload.js' %}"></script>

    <script src="{% static 'photos/js/images-upload.js' %}"></script>
  {% endblock %}

  {% block image_content %}
  <script>
    var URL = '{% url 'ExifReader:image_upload' %}';
  </script>

  <div style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <br>
    <p>This tool uploads photos, reads their Exif metadata, and commits them metadata to the database.
    <br>Click the "Upload photos" button to start.</p>

    <br>

    <form id="FANform" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <!-- {{ formI.as_p }}  THIS JUST ADDED A SEPARATE FIELD/BUTTON; NOT WHAT I NEED -->
      FAN: <input type="text" name="FANfield" id="FANfield"><br><br>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary js-upload-photos">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-upload"></span>
        Upload photos
      </button>

      <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="image" multiple
             style="display: none;"
             data-url="{% url 'ExifReader:image_upload' %}"
             data-form-data='{"csrfmiddlewaretoken": "{{ csrf_token }}"}'>
     </form>
  </div>

  <div class="modal" id="modal-progress" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 id="modal-title" class="modal-title">Uploading...</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="progress" style="height: 42px;">
            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="height: 42px; width: 0%;">0%</div>
          </div>
          <br>
          <button id="done-button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="display: block; margin: 0 auto;">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-upload"></span>
            Done. View uploaded images.
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  {% endblock %}

{% endblock %}
```

```
// images-upload.js
$(function () {
  $(".js-upload-photos").click(function () {
    $("#fileupload").click();
  });
  $("#fileupload").fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    sequentialUploads: false,  /* 1. SEND THE FILES ONE BY ONE */
    start: function (e) {  /* 2. WHEN THE UPLOADING PROCESS STARTS, SHOW THE MODAL */
      var FANfield = $('#FANfield').val();
      console.log(FANfield);
      var data = {'FAN':FANfield}
      $.post(URL, data, function(response){
        if (response === 'success'){
          console.log('success')
        }else{
          console.log('failure')
        }
      });
      $("#modal-progress").modal("show");
      $("#done-button").css("visibility","hidden");
    },
    stop: function (e) {  /* 3. WHEN THE UPLOADING PROCESS FINALIZE, HIDE THE MODAL */
      $("#modal-progress").modal("show");
      $("#modal-title").text("Done uploading");
      $("#done-button").css("visibility","visible");
      $("#done-button").click(function() {
        window.location = '/image_display'
      });
    },
    progressall: function (e, data) {  /* 4. UPDATE THE PROGRESS BAR */
      var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
      var strProgress = progress + "%";
      $(".progress-bar").css({"width": strProgress});
      $(".progress-bar").text(strProgress);
    },

  });

});
```

```
# views.py
class image_upload(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    def get(self, request):
        formI = ImageForm(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)
        return render(self.request, 'ExifReader/images_upload.html', {'formI': formI})

    def post(self, request):
        formI = ImageForm(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)
        formSave = formI.save(commit=False)
        formE = ExifForm(self.request.POST, instance=exif())
        if formI.is_valid() and formE.is_valid():
            photo = formI.save(commit=False)
            FANinput = self.request.POST.get('FAN') # Is this how I should get the js var?
            photo.FAN = FANinput
            photo.user = request.user
            photo.save()
```